# How to use variable outside the task in gradle script

Tags: gradle

I am stuck in a situation where need to read a file (for some values, let's say version number) from inside a war file and use it somewhere else in the same script (I am exploding the war file for this purpose using a **Copy** task). To explain the need, I will write down with the example below:

#### *Defined the variable:*

```
def projVersion = "NULL"
```

#### *Exploding the war:*

```
task explodedWar(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("$buildPath/projectName.war")
    into file("$buildPath/projectName")
}
```

#### *Reading the file from exploded folder and getting a value:*

```
task warVersion(dependsOn : ['explodedWar']) <<{
        Properties versionFile = new Properties()
        versionFile.load(new FileInputStream("$buildPath/projectName/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"))
        ext.projVersion = versionFile.getProperty("Version")
}
```

#### *When Using the variables new value outside the task (This part is throwing Error):*

```
println "Variables new value: " + warVersion.projVersion
```

#### *When Using the variables new value inside some other task (This part is Successful):*

```
task VersionPrint(dependsOn : ['warVersion']) <<{
    println "Project Version under print task" + warVersion.projVersion
}
```

Basically, I am able to use the new value of the variable inside any other ***task*** in the same script, but when I am trying to use the variables new value outside the task areas (sorry but it's a need), it is throwing error:

#### *Error (When using variable outside the task) ****

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Scripts'.
> Could not find property 'projVersion' on task ':warVersion'
```

Let me know, Am I trying to achieve something which is achievable? or is it going to be rule breaking way for gradle? 
If it is possible what I am searching for, please let me know the solution, how to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not thinking about the [build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) correctly.

When you define the `warVersion` task, which depends on `explodedWar`, you're telling Gradle that you want to set the property `projVersion` during the execution of the `warVersion` task.

This means that you can't attempt to read the property until **after** the `warVersion` task is run. Otherwise, it will not be defined. If you attempt to "use the value outside of a task", you're no longer waiting for the `warVersion` task to run. Code that is outside of the scope of a task will be executed during the *configuration* phase, not the *execution* phase.

> when I am trying to use the variables new value outside the task areas (sorry but it's a need), it is throwing error:

You need to refactor how you define the `projVersion` variable.

1. You could refactor your code so you don't need to use the value outside of tasks.
2. You could use the new [`PropertyState`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/release-notes.html#public-type-for-representing-lazily-evaluated-properties) API for lazy-evaluated properties.
3. You could change your logic to execute during the configuration phase.

The last is not ideal as it bypasses task conveniences, such as up-to-date checking. However, you can try it out by changing your copy task to call [`Project#copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:copy(groovy.lang.Closure)), then read the properties file and declare your properties value, all outside of the scope of tasks:

```
copy {
    from zipTree("$buildPath/projectName.war")
    into file("$buildPath/projectName")
}

Properties versionFile = new Properties()
versionFile.load(new FileInputStream("$buildPath/projectName/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"))
ext.projVersion = versionFile.getProperty("Version")
```

This code will be executing during the configuration phase. Now, anywhere after this point you should be able to reference `ext.projVersion`.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks a lot It worked! 
Previously I tried putting Properties block outside the task but was using Task to explodedWar (**task explodedWar(type: Copy)**) the same way (when I was trying multiple ways) with unsuccess. This time I went through your solution (**copy {}**) and it worked for me :-)

Thanks a lot friend.!